# Render partial view with brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting with rails.
I'm trying to render partial view in my controller's method, but I'm gettin with brackets.

My appplication_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def inline_error(field, messages_bag)
    if msg = messages_bag.errors.full_messages_for(field).first
      msg = '<small class="error">'+msg+'</small>'
      return msg.html_safe
    end
  end
  helper_method :inline_error

  #nevermind on param
  def take_flash(type)
    render "class/flash", :layout => false
  end
  helper_method :take_flash
end
```

my class/_flash.html.rb file:

```
hello
```

and I'm gettin

```
["hello"]
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: you have two halper methods but how do you use it?

Comment: <%= take_flash('blahblah') %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there are two different `render` methods, one is defined on ActionView, and the other one is defined on ActionController - they slightly differ in what they do. What you need here is `render` of the view:

```
def take_flash(type)
  view_context.render "class/flash"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the usage of helpers and partials. They are both used to generate segments of view code but you don't need to use both at once. 
In your case you can either pass your param to the partial directly, and remove the helper.

Your view:

```
<%= render 'flash', locals: {my_param: 'blahblah'} %>
```

Your _flash partial:

```
Hello <%= blahblah %>
```

Or you can pass it to the helper and remove the partial.

Your view:

```
<%= take_flash('blahblah') %>
```

Your helper method (define this in a helper file, not your controller):

```
def take_flash(my_param)
  "Hello #{blahblah}"
end
```

Both approaches have the same outcome.

Comment: Generally i wanted to do wrapper for flash messages, because flash.now[:notice] renders only text, without html - is other way to do this?

Comment: You should still put the flash into either a partial or a helper, you don't even need to pass a flash to the method you choose, they both can access any publicly available variables such as flashes. The key thing is to use one method or the other, not both. Rendering a partial from a helper method that only renders a partial is an unnecessary middleman, just go straight to the partial from your view.